# How to get dynamic dropdownlist control from gridview when click btnDoAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

How do I get a dynamic dropdownlist control from a gridview when clicking on btnDoAction

I'm trying to get a dropdownlist control when I click btnDoAction to row, but when I'm looking for the dropdownlist control it always returns null, I'm changing dropdownlist ID in RowDataBound 'cause I populated listItems depending row ID.

[image: this is what I want]

**Code behing**

`protected void gvLista_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

string varId = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id"));
var ctrlDDlActions = e.Row.Cells1.FindControl("ddlActions") as DropDownList;
ctrlDDlActions.ID = ctrlDDlActions.ID + "" + varId.Replace("-", "");
}
}`

```
protected void BtnDoAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var id = Guid.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);

var varId = id.ToString().Replace("-", "_");

            var control = "ddlActions_" + varId;
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();    
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvLista.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                       
                        ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl(control);                            
                }
            }

var selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue; //<--- ddl is null 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching control only by full ID? that is to say: `(DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlActions")`

Answer (score 0):

When grabbing the ddl from the rowdataboud, look for it like this (note the e):

```
  ddl = (DropDownList)e.row.FindControl(control);
```

You are trying to set the selected value for the DropDownList you created. What is the value you are trying to set it to? Looks to me like you are trying to set ddl to some value that you havent set;

```
 var selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue; //<--- ddl is null
  // maybe something like
 var selectedVal = "someval"
 ddl.SelectedValue = selectedVal;
```

What is "var selectedValue"? I don't see where that gets set, therefore it is not the ddl that's null its "var selectedValue".

Comment: thank you Jobesk for answer...  but the problem is that ddl came NULL. I mean ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl(control); doesn't find the dropdownlist control in my gridview...

Answer (score 0):

guys... I found the answer.. thank you for your feeds... the solution that I found is this:

`protected void BtnDoAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            var id = Guid.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);
        
        var control = "ddlActions";

        var ddl = (DropDownList)gvLista.Rows[i].FindControl(control);

        //Now I can read my dropdownlist in my gridview just passing de RowIndex
//you don't need to change the dropdownlist ID in RowDataBound, just let it with the 
//same ID




    }`